# Share hash with multiple domains?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cookies

I'm developing a simple JavaScript application for an insurance company, where users can calculate their monthly fee on one website and then will be redirected to another website where they can fill their insurance application. The calculator app will run on the websites of multiple resellers, eg www.reseller.com. If a user presses "calculate", an ajax request to www.insurance.com calculates the results and generates a hash as a unique identifier for the calculation and sends it back to www.reseller.com. If the user agrees to the result, he can go to www.insurance.com/order, where he can place the application.

What's the best way to share the calculation hash with both domains without using get parameters?

I've already tried to set the hash value as a cookie in the ajax result on reseller.com, but since the cookie is placed on the same domain, the final order form on insurance.com can't read it.

Is there any way?

Comment: what about a post parameter in the ajax

Comment: If the hash doesn't have to be secret it could just be part of the query string. For example, www.reseller.com?hash=123456